# c argv[count]+2

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I have this code `strncpy(szOutput, argv[count]+2, sizeof(szOutput) - 1);`

The arvg is a char **argv. What I was wondering is what does the +2 stand for.

Thank you.

Comment: `char **` is **not** a 2D array. A pointer is not an array (and vice-versa).

Comment: @Elizabeth A It depends on what argv[count] stores.

Comment: I strongly suspect, it is meant to add `2` to `argv[count]`.

Comment: usually such code means `ignore first 2 symbols from string during copy`, for example command line arguments usually pre-pended with `--`, but you need only actual argument name

Comment: @Lasane I believe you are right because just before that it is checkign for the first 2 symbols

 if ((argv[count][0] == '-') &&((argv[count][1] == 'b').... 

So it makes sense to copy anything after the first 2 symbols are checked. I just have never see it before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the line: `strncpy(szOutput, argv[count]+2, sizeof(szOutput) - 1);`

the second parameter: `argv[count]+2`

the meaning of the second parameter.

1. `argv[count] it is a pointer to some NUL terminated array of char passed in from the command line
2. the `+2` means the address of the 3rd char in the array selected by `count`